# Web API - FormData is always null when using MultipartFormDataStreamProvider

Tags: file-upload, asp.net-web-api, multipartform-data

I am trying to post a input file along with some extra input from user using jquery to Web API.

In web API I am using MultipartFormDataStreamProvider to read the data, here is code :-

```
 var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(<some local path>);
 await request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
 var formData = provider.FormData;
 foreach (string key in formData.Keys)
 {
 }
 foreach (var file in provider.FileData)
 {
    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(file.LocalFileName);
 }
```

In FileData I am getting the input file but the FormData has no keys.

I referred below article to implement this

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/sending-html-form-data,-part-2

I am not sure what is wrong here...if anyone could please help me sort out this issue?

Comment: I'm not sure if it makes a difference, but in the article you reference, he uses the formData.AllKeys property. Microsoft's documentation on the difference between Keys and AllKeys isn't clear either. Worth a try though.

Comment: @Brett formData.AllKeys is also empty.

Comment: Hmm. Just to be sure, is this code inside a `public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post()` function on your controller, and the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute is set on your `<form />` tag? Just covering all the bases first.

Comment: Yes its a public method and the form tag has enctype="multipart/form-data". I am also not sure what is wrong there...but I have found an alternative to solve this..Thanks for your efforts @Brett.

Comment: This is how I am doing now-  
            var provider = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider();
        
            await request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
      
            foreach (HttpContent ctnt in provider.Contents)
            {
                if (ctnt != null && ctnt.Headers.ContentDisposition != null)
                {
                    if (ctnt.Headers.ContentDisposition.Name == "\"fileToUpload\"")
                    {
             }
      //and so on...
                 }
             }

Comment: @devson  Could you be kind enough to create an answer with your new solution?  I'm also having the issue and feel the community might benefit from a source post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code is working for me-

```
var provider = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider();
    await request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider); 
    foreach (HttpContent ctnt in provider.Contents) 
    { 
            if (ctnt != null && ctnt.Headers.ContentDisposition != null) 
            { 
               if (ctnt.Headers.ContentDisposition.Name == "\"fileToUpload\"") 
               { 
                  //code goes here
               } 
            } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do each of your form input controls (`<input />, <select />, <textarea />`, etc.) in your HTML have name attributes? A form input control with no name cannot be successful (i.e. browsers will not post their values).

Comment: Yes they have name attributes.